# npm requires a peer of

Tags: npm, vuejs2, dependencies

My vue project stops working when I try to npm install any new package. I was installing axios.

First I got,

> ```
> npm install
> npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN url-loader@1.1.1 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@3.4.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0
>   but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN webpack-dev-server@3.1.10 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but
>   none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> ```

so I install those packages,

```
npm install ajv-keywords@3.2.0  ajv@^6.0.0 url-loader@1.1.1  webpack@^4.0.0 webpack-dev-middleware@3.4.0  webpack@^4.0.0 webpack-dev-server@3.1.10  webpack@^4.0.0
```

Then I get these warnings,

> ```
> npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2 requires a peer of webpack@^3.1.0
>   but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN html-webpack-plugin@2.30.1 requires a peer of
>   webpack@1 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc || ^3 but
>   none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> ```

which tell me to use webpack 3

So I ran,

```
npm install webpack@^3.1.0 extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2 html-webpack-plugin@2.30.1
```

Which then gives me the following warning, telling to use webpack4.

> ```
> npm WARN url-loader@1.1.1 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none
>   is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@3.4.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0
>   but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN webpack-dev-server@3.1.10 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none
>   is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> ```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried installing webpack@^4.0.0?

```
npm install webpack@^4.0.0
```

Comment: If you read the first `npm install` command in the OP you'll see that it does include `webpack@^4.0.0` (...it's the 4th, 6th, and 8th package in the list of packages to install).

Comment: npm install webpack@^4.0.0
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2 requires a peer of webpack@^3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN html-webpack-plugin@2.30.1 requires a peer of webpack@1 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc || ^3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ webpack@4.25.1
added 25 packages from 9 contributors, removed 60 packages, updated 4 packages and audited 17562 packages in 15.565s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: @Rafaël Moser After your question, I did npm install webpack@^4.0.0 as you can see in comment just above this, and this still gives me warnings

Comment: @RobC yes I shouldn't have repeated webpack@^4.0.0 so many times

Comment: Seems that I created my project using $ vue init <template-name> <project-name> but this is only correct for vue-cli version 2.9. In vue-cli version 3 you need to do $ vue create <template-name> <project-name>